# makefile not running commands and "eating" first letter of variable

Tags: makefile

I have a function like this:

```
build:
    git_branch="$(`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`)"
    ifeq("$git_branch", 'development')
        tag="development"
    else("$git_branch", 'staging')
        tag="staging"
    else("$git_branch", 'master')
        tag="production"
    endif
    echo "tag is $(tag)"
```

when I run `make build` this is the output

```
git_branch=""
ifeq("it_branch", 'development')
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"it_branch",'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq("it_branch", 'development')'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

so first, the git branch is empty, when it shouldn't. if I run this command on console, I get the branch name correctly, second, whats up with the variable being evaluated as `it_branch` instead `git_branch`?

Well, I'm kinda new to makefiles, I went through the docs and couldn't catch anything I'm possibly doing wrong

*Edit*

I changed to this:

```
git_branch:= $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
ifeq ($(git_branch), "development")
    tag:= "development"
else($(git_branch), "staging")
    tag:= "staging"
else($(git_branch), "master")
    tag:= "production"
endif

build:
    echo "tag is $(tag)"
    echo "branch is $(git_branch)"
```

the tag is empty, but git_branch is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
git_branch:= $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
ifeq ($(git_branch), development)
    tag:=development
endif
ifeq ($(git_branch), staging)
    tag:=staging
endif
ifeq ($(git_branch), master)
    tag:=production
endif

build:
    echo "tag is $(tag)"
```

Short explanation: You're confusing shell variables with make variables. Your logic for the make variables doesn't have to be inside a *recipe*, in fact, this doesn't make much sense because these things are interpreted by make (while the recipe is executed by a shell make launches).

In `make`, you have to enclose variable names in parantheses, otherwise it is assumed they only have one character.

Comment: it "kinda" works...the branch is correctly evaluated, but the tag is empty

Comment: Well, works for me, output: `tag is production`. Tested on win10 with msys2's `GNU Make 4.2.1`.

Comment: @LuizE your changes are wrong, you compare e.g. against `"master"` instead of just `master`. `make` syntax is different from the shell's....

Comment: If I put just `master` without quotes or anything, I get `Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: @LuizE. please pay attention to details. The `make` `ifeq` statement needs a space before the values to be compared: `ifeq ($(git_branch), master)` is correct, `ifeq($(git_branch), master)` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If a makefile variable contains multiple characters you have to enclose the name with parentheses not quotes. Evaluate shell commands with `shell`:

```
git_branch=$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
ifeq($(git_branch), 'development')
```